# MySQL error 1064 (42000) when using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Currently getting an error "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1" when I run this code:

```
    def initiate_sale():
        while True:
            cx_shopped_before = input('Has customer shopped with us before? Y/N: ')
            if cx_shopped_before.upper() == 'Y':
                cust_email = input('Please enter customers email address')
                with mysql.connector.connect(host=HOSTNAME, user=USER_NAME, password=PASSWORD) as mysql_connection:
                    with mysql_connection.cursor() as mysql_cursor:
                        mysql_cursor.execute('USE florist')
                        query = "SELECT CusID, cus_fname, cus_lname FROM customer WHERE cus_email = (%s)"
                        mysql_cursor.execute(query, cust_email)
                        break
            elif cx_shopped_before.upper() == 'N':
                pass
            else:
                print('Invalid choice, use Y or N')
```

I believe it to be a simple bracket or comma because its just a single item in a tuple in the execute statement but i can't find where. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tuple to replace the pace holder, it needs atm least 2 dimensions

```
 query = """SELECT CusID, cus_fname, cus_lname FROM customer WHERE cus_email = (%s)"""
 mysql_cursor.execute(query, (cust_email,))
```

Comment: this solved the issue although it did introduce a new error 'Unread result' but to fix that i had to add in buffered=True in the mysql.connector section

Comment: this is depending on what you trying to do you can also use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't think you need the parentheses around `%s`

```
query = "SELECT CusID, cus_fname, cus_lname FROM customer WHERE cus_email = %s"
```

Comment: mysql doesn't mind parentesis around a value, so this is also not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysql_cursor.execute(query, tuple(cust_email))` instead of `mysql_cursor.execute(query, cust_email)`.

Comment: in python a tuple needs at least 2 dimensions

Comment: doing this resulted in this error "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"